# Azure DevOps REST api - Run pipeline with variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-pipelines

I have a pipeline on Azure Devops that I'm trying to run programatically/headless using the REST api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

So far so good, I can auth and start a run. I would like to pass data to this pipeline which the docs suggests is possible using `variables` in the request body. My request body:

```
{
    "variables": {
        "HELLO_WORLD": {
            "isSecret": false,
            "value": "HelloWorldValue"
        }
    }
}
```

My pipeline YAML looks like this:

```
trigger: none

pr: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      KEY=$(HELLO_WORLD)
      echo "Hello world key: " $KEY
```

This however gives me an error that "HELLO_WORLD: command not found".

I have tried adding a "HELLO_WORLD" variable to the pipeline and enabled the "Let users override this value when running this pipeline"-setting. This results in the `HELLO_WORLD` variable no longer being unknown, but instead its stuck on its initial value and not set when i trigger a run with the REST api

How do you pass variables to a pipeline using the REST api? It is important that the variable value is set only for a specific run/build

I found another API to run a build, but it seems like you cannot use Personal Access Token auth with it, like you can with the pipeline api - only OAuth2 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do it with both the [Runs API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and  [Build Queue API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), both work with Personal Access Tokens. For which one is the better/preferred, see this question: [Difference between Azure Devops Builds - Queue vs run pipeline REST APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63819907/difference-between-azure-devops-builds-queue-vs-run-pipeline-rest-apis), but in short the Runs API will be the more future proof option

## Option 1: Runs API

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/pipelines/{{PipelineId}}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Your body will be of type `application/json` (HTTP header `Content-Type` is set to `application/json`) and similar to the below, just replace `resources.repositories.self.refName` with the appropriate value

```json
{
    "resources": {
        "repositories": {
            "self": {
                "refName": "refs/heads/main"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "HELLO_WORLD": {
            "isSecret": false,
            "value": "HelloWorldValue"
        }
    }
}
```

## Option 2: Build API

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0
```

Your body will be of type `application/json` (HTTP header `Content-Type` is set to `application/json`), something similar to below, just replace `definition.id` and `sourcebranch` with appropriate values. Please also note the "stringified" content of the parameter section (it should be a string representation of a json map)

```json
{
    "parameters": "{\"HELLO_WORLD\":\"HelloWorldValue\"}",
    "definition": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "sourceBranch": "refs/heads/main"
}
```

Comment: Option 1 works for me! Thank you. I needed to add `resources` to my request... Would have been nice if it would give you an error for that but hey, seems to work now, thanks again

Comment: It works without the `resources` block also, it will fall back to the default branch.

Comment: whats the syntax for more than one variables?

Comment: @LarsPellarin just add the additional variables to the serialized json array `"parameters": "{\"HELLO_WORLD\": \"HelloWorldValue\", \"ANOTHER_KEY\": \"ANOTHER_VALUE\"}"`

Answer (score 4):

Here's the way I solved it....

The REST call:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/<myOrg>/<myProject>/_apis/pipelines/17/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

The body of the request:

```
{
    "resources": {
        "repositories": {
            "self": {
                "refName": "refs/heads/main"
            }
        }
    },
    "templateParameters": {
        "A_Parameter": "And now for something completely different."
    }
}
```

Note: I added an authorization header with basic auth containing a username (any name will do) and password (your PAT token value). Also added a Content-Type application/json header.

Here's the entire yaml pipeline I used:

```
parameters:
- name: A_Parameter
  displayName: A parameter
  default: noValue
  type: string
 
trigger:
- none
 
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
 
steps:
 
- script: |
    echo '1 - using dollar sign parens, p dot A_Parameter is now: ' $(parameters.A_Parameter)
    echo '2 - using dollar sign double curly braces, p dot A_Parameter is now::' ${{ parameters.A_Parameter }} '::'
    echo '3 - using dollar sign and only the var name: ' $(A_Parameter)
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

And here's the output from the pipeline log. Note that only the second way properly displayed the value.

```
1 - using dollar sign parens, p dot A_Parameter is now: 
2 - using dollar sign double curly braces, p dot A_Parameter is now:: And now for something completely different. :: 
3 - using dollar sign and only the var name:
```

Comment: Lol, blizzville, I find myself doing the same echo script, too.  Can never remember which syntax is appropriate.