# Configure pipeline to trigger multiple pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I had around 30 pipelines (each doing its own build, deploy, tests) , all in same project.

Instead of having to manually trigger all 30 pipelines each time, I wanted to create a separate pipeline YAML which on running it can trigger all the 30 individual pipelines.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I understand from documentation there is concept to add the pipeline triggers. However, I was not able to understand if single yaml can trigger individual pipelines - and if so, whether it is getting triggered at the completion of the pipeline or at the start of it.

Flow I was looking for is -

There are 30 individual pipelines each having complete flow for services:

```
stages:
   stageA
   stageB
   stageC
```

Now, I was trying to create a pipeline yaml `all_apps.yml` which triggers all the 30 individual pipelines at once.

Comment: You should add a trigger *to each pipeline*.

Comment: @DanielMann Adding individual triggers should work. However, is there a way to pass pipeline parameters from main pipeline to all individual pipelines? Does azure allow doing that?

Answer (score 1):

> Configure pipeline to trigger multiple pipelines

There are several ways to accomplish it, you can choose the one that suits you.

**First**, we could set the **Build completion** for those 30 pipelines:

Go the edit page of the triggered yaml pipeline(Deploy pipeline), Click the **3dots** and choose **Triggers** :

[image]

Go to Triggers--> Build completion and click add--> Select your triggering pipeline(`all_apps.yml` pipeline):

[image]

**Second**, there is an extension [Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline), we could use this task to trigger those 30 pipelines.

**Third**, you could it with both the [Runs API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6VcB.png) and  [Build Queue API](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline), both work with Personal Access Tokens. You can also use loops to make REST API calls more graceful. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66185420/azure-devops-rest-api-run-pipeline-with-variables) for some more details.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer ! That’s very useful info. I was able to get the trigger working for pipeline to be triggered. However, if the individual pipelines had parameters defined in their yaml, it does not trigger the pipeline. Any possible way to handle that?