# Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline with Variables and & Print

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Trying to set up a hello world pipeline which echo's a variable I pass in. Need to trigger via API.
I have the trigger working but I can't get my variable printing to the console.

I've defined a variable called `myVar`

[image: ado image]

Including the PAT conversion as it might save someone else the 3hrs it took me to track down the correct combo.

```sh
MY_PAT=abc1234
B64_PAT=$(printf "%s"":$MY_PAT" | base64)

curl -X POST https://dev.azure.com/***/test/_apis/pipelines/123/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1 \
-H Authorization: Basic $64_PAT \
-H Content-Type: application-json
{
  "parameters": "{ \"myVar\": \"foo\" }"
}
```

My task is a command line script (task 2.*):

```sh
echo Hello world
echo $(myVar)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66185420/azure-devops-rest-api-run-pipeline-with-variables. See the "with runs api". Confusing that there's two APIs but that syntax worked.

Comment: Hi john smith; if your question is about why the pipeline is not printing the variable, then the information about the API call is not relevant.

Comment: What is relevant is your pipeline; can you paste in the yaml, for the task where you are expecting to print the variable out?