# Referencing variables in yaml that are passed from ADO REST Api

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to run a pipeline i have with variables which are being sent from an application in a POST request to ADO pipeline. Trying to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66185420/azure-devops-rest-api-run-pipeline-with-variables?newreg=22d3a0eb26c04856b73b177919021eb1) post with runs api:
However I'm not sure how to reference these variables in my pipeline. I want to use terraform in my pipeline with some of these variables. This may be something simple I just have not found yet but any help is appreciated

I have searched online and some places say environment variables? Would appreciate help in how to reference these if thats the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reference a pipeline variable assigned via the REST API [Runs - Run Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) in terraform, you can refer to the following example. In this example, I create a new project and define the name of the project using the variable "projname".

1. Declare the variable `projname` and refer to it using `var.projname` in `main.tf`.

```
variable "projname" {
  type = string
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azuredevops = {
      source = "microsoft/azuredevops"
      version = ">= 0.1.0"
    }
  }
}

resource "azuredevops_project" "project" {
  name               = var.projname
  visibility         = "private"
  version_control    = "Git"
  work_item_template = "Agile"
  description        = "Created by Terraform"
}
```

2. Add a variable named "projname" in the UI and leave its value empty.
   [image]
3. Passs the value of `projname` to the terraform scripts using `-var "projname=$(projname)"` in your plan and apply command.

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: Terraform Plan and Apply
  env: 
    AZDO_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
    AZDO_ORG_SERVICE_URL: $(System.CollectionUri)
  inputs:
    script: |
      terraform plan -input=false -var "projname=$(projname)"
      terraform apply -input=false -var "projname=$(projname)" -auto-approve
```

If you are not making changes to DevOps org, there is no need to define `env` variables shown above.

If you are using Terraform task, you can add `-var "projname=$(projname)"` in `commandOptions`.

```
- task:TerraformTaskV3@3
  displayName: 'Terraform Plan'
  inputs:
    command: 'plan'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    environmentServiceName: '<service_connection_name>'
    commandOptions: '-var "projname=$(projname)"'
```

4. Run REST API [Runs - Run Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to trigger the pipeline.

Request body:

```
{
    "resources": {
        "repositories": {
            "self": {
                "refName": "refs/heads/main"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "projname": {
            "isSecret": false,
            "value": "TerraformPro"
        }
    }
}
```